# Does it matter in which order you use prefetch_related and filter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The title says it all.

Let's take a look at this code for example:

```py
objs = Model.objects.prefetch_related('model2').filter()
objs.first().model2_set.first().field

                  vs

objs = Model.objects.filter().prefetch_related('model2')
objs.first().model2_set.first().field
```

##### Question

When using `prefetch_related()` first, does Django fetch all the `ManyToOne`/`ManyToMany` relations without taking into consideration `.filter()` and after everything is fetched, the filter is applied?

IMO, that doesn't matter since there's still one query executed at the end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you specify `prefetch_related` as long as it's before any records are fetched.  Personally I put things like `prefetch_related`, `select_related`. and `only` at the end of the chain but that just feels more expressive to me from a code readability perspective.

But that is not true of all manager methods.  Some methods do have different effects depending on their position in the chain, for example `order_by` can have positional significance when used with `distinct` (group by).